# Как проиграть собственный рингтон?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение с чатом. Каждый раз, когда в чате приходит сообщение надо проигрывать определённый звук. Звук нестандартный, он лежит в res/raw.

Я пробовал:

```java
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.chat_sound);
mp.start();
```

Но тут два недостатка:

1. Громкость звука регулируется в разделе Media, а мне нужно чтобы громкость была как у рингтона
2. Если начать проигрывать заново звук, в то время когда предыдущий звук ещё не доиграл, следующий не проигрывается.

Как мне проиграть собственный звуковой файл как уведомление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте параметр `sound` в вашему объекту уведомления:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(...);
...
notification.sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + 
        "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notificationsound );
```

Либо через билдер:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
...
builder.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + 
        "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notificationsound ););
...
Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Чтобы воспроизводить звук без уведомления, нужно воспользоваться классом `SoundPool`, который подходит для частого воспроизведения коротких звуков (в отличии от `MediaPlayer`):

```
SoundPool soundPool;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    AudioAttributes atr = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build();

    soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
            .setMaxStreams(1)
            .setAudioAttributes(atr)
            .build();
} else {
    //noinspection deprecation
    soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
}

int soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.notification, 1);

// Воспроизведение в нужном месте 
soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

Стоит заметить, что метод загрузки звука в память `load()` - асинхронный. Подробный 
[урок по `SoundPool`](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/239-urok-127-media-soundpool.html).

Comment: Извините что не сразу ответил. Я попробовал данный код. Это не совсем то что мне нужно. Мне нужно чтобы звук проигрывался как уведомление, но без самого уведомления. Т.е. чтобы в трее не всплывало уведомление. А если я пытаюсь отправить это уведомление через NotificationManager, то оно ругается что не установлены параметры, такие как маленькая иконка.

Comment: @cheerful_weasel Дополнил ответ для вашего случая