# SoundPool или MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

Доехал до части звука в своем приложении, начал изучать вопрос и встал в тупик. Мне нужно зацикливать короткие звуки (менее 1с). Давай читать, вроде нужно использовать SoundPool для этих целей, но по части саундпула инфы не так много хорошей, непонятные условия проверок версии андроеда, какие-то постоянные ошибки (либо сложности) у людей, а кто-то и вовсе пишет, что SoundPool сломали :( И там же пишут, что данная задача хорошо решается с MediaPlayer, даже удобнее якобы. Вот и стою на распутье. Господа программисты, кто с чем работает, кто что юзал, что все-таки для чего и как что работает?

Comment: Для коротких частых звуков `SoundPool` для музыки и подобного `MediaPlayer`. Посмотрите этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703845/14141) (вторую часть)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс SoundPool управляет и воспроизводит аудиоресурсы проекта для приложений.

SoundPool - это набор образцов, которые могут быть загружены в память из ресурса APK или из файла в файловой системе. Библиотека SoundPool использует службу **MediaPlayer** для декодирования аудио в необработанный 16-битный моно или стерео поток PCM. Это позволяет приложениям поставлять сжатые потоки без потери загрузки ЦП и задержки при распаковке во время воспроизведения.

В дополнение к воспроизведению с низкой задержкой SoundPool также может управлять количеством аудиопотоков, отображаемых за один раз. Когда объект SoundPool сконструирован, параметр maxStreams устанавливает максимальное количество потоков, которые могут воспроизводиться за один раз из этого единственного SoundPool. SoundPool отслеживает количество активных потоков. Если максимальное количество потоков превышено, SoundPool автоматически остановит ранее воспроизведенный поток, основанный сначала на приоритете, а затем по возрасту в пределах этого приоритета. Ограничение максимального количества потоков помогает ограничить загрузку ЦП и уменьшить вероятность того, что микширование звука повлияет на визуальные эффекты или производительность пользовательского интерфейса.

SoundPool отлично работает, в API 21 используйте билдер:
**SoundPool.Builder** так как использовать конструктор класса устаревшая практика. **deprecated!**

> This constructor was deprecated in API level 21. use SoundPool.Builder
>   instead to create and configure a SoundPool instance

Comment: ещё есть вещи которые можно сделать используя только SoundPool, например переключение в рантайме поток с большого на малый динамик.

Comment: я не уверен, что это невозможно сделать через MediaPlayer, мб просто удобней, но не только